# How to get data from a website After I logged in!(Html Agility pack)

Tags: c#, .net, html

My goal is only to get data from the .Net web browser. First I loaded the log-in page(for gmail for example) using Html agility pack,

```
public void start_parsing(string URL_) 
{
   var webGet = new HtmlWeb();            
   var document = webGet.Load(URL_);
}
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{                
     string url = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();             
     start_parsing(webBrowser1.Url.ToString());    
}
```

The "document" gets the Html data successfully at first(home page), but when I log in The "document"variable contains no data, am sure there are some functions that must be added, but I have no idea what are they.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: it would help if you posted a more thorough example...you mention logging in, but you have basically no code there to work with...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are still logged in?  Creating a `new HtmlWeb()` would get rid of all cookies that might keep your logged in session data.

You may need to copy the header items after logging in, or make sure the code reuses the same HtmlWeb object so it keeps the same Header values.

Comment: It don't think am still logged in,not sure! I copied the HtmlWeb and made it a public variable but still no change!

Comment: Looking at HtmlWeb, setting the property `webGet.UseCookies` is probably needed as well.  To debug you can dump your `document` variable out to a file and open it with a webbrowser to see what the code is actually downloading.  One simple way to do that: `File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\test.html", document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml)`

Comment: I tried doing this and the page it saved is the same as the log-in page
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/x/quu8epfhjlzr/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=ecobh&nui=5&btmpl=mobile